# Price History of FPGA

Tags: fpga, asic, cost, pricing

My goal is to extrapolate (or estimate) the future prices of FPGAs and/or ASICs.

1. Does anyone know of the price history of FPGAs or ASICs?  I am looking for a source of information.

   - I know that today FPGA's can be categorized into three basic categories (High end, mid range, and low end FPGA).  I'm much more interested in the High end product range, but any information is helpful.
2. Are there any academic or business journals that study the prices of FPGA or ASICs?

Any input on this topic is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Moore's Law would be a good place to start. It's still holding.

Comment: *"Prediction is very difficult, especially about the future."* -- Niels Bohr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [octopart](http://octopart.com) for that. Look for a component, and if you found one with an authorized distributor, on the detail page you get a history chart. Look for example at the [XC9572XL history](http://octopart.com/xc9572xl-10pc44c-xilinx-432812). More information is in the [octopart blog](http://octopart.com/blog/archives/2012/7/historical-pricing).

Comment: I don't see any price history on the page you linked. I see prices for different quantities, but no history of price by date.

Comment: @ThePhoton, there's a comment on the blog that says "We have some A/B tests going on, some of which don't have it. Try clearing your cookies and giving it another shot."